# Creating slanted dashed line in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create a slanted dashed line in Adobe Illustrator, something like this:

[image]

I've tried to create a dashed line and then apply shear to it, but for some reason when I do the shear nothing happens.
I'm using Adobe Illustrator from the Creative Cloud.

Any suggestions? Maybe another way to do the slanted dashes?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I don't understand what the issue is. You can merely [create dashes for any path using the Stroke Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAN6f.png)

Comment: I need the dashes to be slanted, at an angle. I've created vertical dashes but can't shear them to the desired angle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Draw a path and set the dashes correctly...

[image]

Then choose `Object > Expand Appearance`, Then `Object > Expand`

You can then shear the shapes however you need.

[image]

The great thing about using dashes this way is you can use the **Width Tool** and the **Stroke Profile** to create bordering shapes with the dashes if necessary:

[image]

Comment: Works great !!! Didn't know that the expand thing is needed for this to work

Answer (score 7):

Create a vertical line and apply a 30°- 60° shear to it (depending how slanted you'd like it)

Then go to **Effects → Distort and Transform → Transform** and set it to move horizontally and add in the number of copies you'd like.
[image]

If you need to edit the lines individually later on, you can go to **Object → Expand Appearance**

Answer (score 4):

Not difficult: for this you create a custom brush - you create the rectangles you've posted as vector, and select them, and go to Brushes>New Brush, choose Art Brush, set the Art Brush preferences you prefer for corners, recolouring etc, et viola! You've just made your own brush you can apply to *any* vector stroke.

Here I've quickly roughed the angled strokes from your image

[image]

I've selected them and gone to the Brush palette, and chosen New Brush

[image]

In the popup dialogue I've chosen Art Brush

[image]

Set the preferences I want for corners, recolour etc

[image]

And applied that new brush to a bezier vector - done!

[image]

Hope this helps.

EDIT: ***OH and BTW*** - the Stroke Width tool (and / or tablet pen pressure) still work perfectly with this method, allowing for all kinds of interesting effects - sort of 90's tribal tattoo style!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Create a pattern brush from a module made with 4 slanted rectangles.

[image: patternbrush]

Answer (score 1):

Begin by creating a rectangle and using the pen or line tool create a line from the top of the rectangle to the bottom at an angle.

[image]

Next using the move tool while holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> drag and copy the line.

[image]

Then using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or going through the menu. Transform again until the lines fill up the rectangle.

[image]

Then you just move the rectangle to the top of the layer stack and make it a clipping mask using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>

[image]

---

For a better look at sheering the stroke.

[image]